# REGEX Splitting a string by spaces and punctuation, EXCEPT apostrophe, but including punctuation in their own section of array

Tags: java, regex

This is what I have:

```
String[] sArray = longString.split("\\s+|(?=\\p{P})");
```

This works great for what I want, except I want to not include an apostrophe.

Everything I've found to do this causes each punctuation to be an element in the result.

Comment: It is easy with Java regex, use character class subtraction: `"\\s+|(?=[\\p{P}&&[^']])"`

Comment: Do you mean you want to include apostrophe as a "word" character, so "can't" is a single element of the result? Or do you mean you want to ignore apostrophes? Or something else?